# Setup SSL on remote MySQL server for mobile app

Tags: mysql, ssl, ubuntu-18.04

I am new to setting up SSL certificates on servers and would need some help to secure a MySQL database connection. I have a simple mobile app (client) which needs to connect to a remote MySQL database (server) connection. I am using AWS EC2 for the remote server and I have installed Let's Encrypt SSL certificates on a domain that I am hosting there. The machine runs on Ubuntu 18.04 and NGINX.

The same server also runs a MySQL database and I want to connect to it securely using a  mobile app client. How can I encrypt the connection between the mobile app aclient and the MySQL database server?

I do have a static ip address for the database server but I am unable to install SSL certificates on the ip address directly. Only the domain name has an associated SSL certificate.

I did some digging around but was unable to find anything that serves my purpose. Any suggestion or reference to an article would greatly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article provides a detailed step by step procedure for securing the connection between a remote MySQL database server and a client.

[Securing a remote MySQL database server connection](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-connect-to-remote-mysql-server-using-ssl-on-ubuntu-18-04/)